# ArcGIS convert TSurf to multipatch without license to use Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6, multipatch

I'm trying to convert a TSurf into [1] polygons shapefile (got this part) and [2] a multipatch.

I tried Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d, but I don't have the license for it. Is there a viable alternative?

I'm working in ArcGIS and would prefer to write this up as a tool using ArcPy.

Worst case scenario, I would have to consider doing this in QGIS. If I do QGIS, is there a ready-to-go plug-in that converts TSurfs to polygons SHP and multipatch?